# How to set the body class in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to add to the body a class "bodyLogin" when in login page and remove it for all other pages.
How should it be done in the angular way?

Comment: Use `ng-app` on the `html` element and then using `ng-class="{ 'bodyLogin' : isUserLoggedIn }"` and an `ng-controller="LoginController"` on the `body` element?

Comment: Thansk, I don't have a property called isUserLoggedIn in my application. I do have an ng-app on my html of course.

Comment: That was an example. The basic idea is to include the `body` element inside your application and set a class on it just like any other element.

Comment: What I did was defining a service that will hold the a property called bodyClass and will have a getter and setter. Then I defined a controller for the body element. Injected the bodyService to it. Used the body service to set and get in the appropriate parts of the code. In the controller there is a scope property called bodyClass and I set ng-class="{{bodyClass}}" , but the value is not getting injected to the class attribute of the body.

Comment: Right syntax is `ng-class="[attribute]"` (array syntax), where attribute is the scope property to watch

Comment: Where is your `ng-app` defined?

Comment: my ng-app is define in the <html> tag

Comment: I'm still facing some issues with auto updating/two way binding. I've set up a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7YCPNERm1PeUXk8AwUQC?p=preview). I'm trying to figure out how I'm gonna make the change in bodyService to affect the body class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jeremy advised I used the ng-class but still had an issue with the auto set of the $scope value inLoginPage to effect the body class. The answer is very simple using the scope inheritance of Angular. The code for implementing body class change dynamically is in this [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YnOFiQ?p=info).

```
app.controller('profileController', function($scope) {
  $scope.setBodyClass('profile');
});
app.controller('loginController', function($scope) {
  $scope.setBodyClass('login');
});

//the controller can use either the bodyService or the app.value bodyClass
//app.controller('bodyController', function($scope, bodyService) {
app.controller('bodyController', function($scope, bodyClass) {
  $scope.setBodyClass = function(_bodyCLass) {
    $scope.bodyClass = _bodyCLass;
    $scope.inLoginPage = ($scope.bodyClass === 'login');
  };
});
```

Update: I changed the plunk to be more clear. the plunk shows now that you can use either the service or the value.

Comment: I have totally confused with your example. See, you didn't inject `bodyService` to `bodyController`, how `setBodyClass` method even works in its scope? And plus, as you've defined a value `bodyClass` for `app` module, what's the use of local variable `bodyClass` in `bodyService` factory?

Comment: Dude, Your example is misleading us! the `bodyService` is totally useless, it doesn't even work at all, you can delete the whole factory to prove that. This piece of code made me thinking over and over and over...shit!

Comment: @nightire, thanks for the comment, I'm sorry that you were misled by the post. I've updated the post and the plunkr, plus tested to see that it still work. let me know if it works for you or not.
cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ng-class` directive, that allow you to dynamically define a class according to an angularjs expression ; you just have to put this directive inside your `body` tag, and then update your model to reflect page's id

More information on `ng-class` : [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

EDIT : be careful with the syntax, as it written in the documentation ; easiest way for your context would be to use the array syntax `ng-class="{{ [ myAttribute ] }}"`

Comment: Thanks for the lead Jeremy.
I'm still facing some issues with auto updating/two way binding. I've set up a plunker here[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7YCPNERm1PeUXk8AwUQC). I'm trying to figure out how I'm gonna make the change in bodyService to affect the bodyClass.